# How to pass username retrieved from perl script as a parameter to another exe file?

Tags: perl

How to pass the variable `user_name` to the exe file `file.exe` as a parameter? Also, tell me if I would actually get the username from the accounting start packet with the `getusername` command.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my $user_name;

print "Hello radiator is executing the exe file...\n";


my $user_name = $p->getUserName;
open my $EX1_PIPE, '|-', 'file.exe'
        or die $!;

print $EX1_PIPE "$_\n"   # i dont know what this line is for
       for qw/username password/;  #  i dont know what this line is for

close $EX1_PIPE or die $!;
```

Comment: The print is writing data to the pipe, and the `for` loop is iterating over the strings 'username' and 'password' (so print is called for each string.)

Comment: *"How to pass the variable user_name to the exe file file.exe as a parameter"* - from where? Another Perl script? bash? Windows cmd?

Comment: Let me explain, i am using the above perl script to run an exe file and pass the username parameter to the exe file. The username is to be retrieved from the accounting start packet sent from the cisco ISG(NAS). As i am new to perl scripting,please review the above sripts and add suitable lines or modifications to get the above requirement fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

`open` is running the command, so you just need to invoke the command
with the desired argument:

```
open my $EX1_PIPE, '|-', "file.exe $user_name" or die "file.exe $!\n";
```

On the other hand, given your comment, it seems you want to pass the username
as input to the script.  If that is the case, perhaps you are looking for:

```
print $EX1_PIPE "$_\n" for ($user_name $password);
```

(You will need to define a variable named `$password`)

Comment: Let me explain, i am using the above perl script to run an exe file and pass the username parameter to the exe file. The username is to be retrieved from the accounting start packet sent from the cisco ISG(NAS). As i am new to perl scripting,please review the above sripts and add suitable lines or modifications to get the above requirement fulfilled.I dont even know the meaning of some lines in the script i provided above, please review and make changes ,as per requirements mentioned. Please help me out. Thanks for your comment.